# How to Round to the Nearest Tenth?

Tags: lua, rounding

Given any number of the sort 78.689 or 1.12 for instance, what I'm looking for is to programmatically round the number to the nearest tenth place after the decimal.

I'm trying to do this in an environment where there is a `math.floor()` function that rounds to the lowest whole number, and as far as I can tell from documentation there's nothing like PHP's `round()` function.

Comment: `string.format("%.1f", percent * 100)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's simple snippet at: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleRound

```
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
  local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

It will misbehave when numDecimalPlaces is negative, but there's more examples on that page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use coercion to do this...
It work just like printf... You can try to do something like in this snippet.

```
value = 8.9756354
print(string.format("%2.1f", value))
-- output: 9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that this is roblox, it would just be easier to make this a global variable instead of making a single module or creating your own gloo.

```
_G.round = function(x, factor) 
    local factor = (factor) and (10 ^ factor) or 0
    return math.floor((x + 0.5) * factor) / factor
end
```

Comment: In regards to Roblox, _G is now deprecated and the platform now recommends storing functions for global use in ModuleScripts. This can be achieved by storing the function inside a table that you return upon importing a module script, or simply returning the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was simply trying to make a string representation of this number... however, I imagine this solution could prove useful to others as well.

```
string.sub(tostring(percent * 100), 1, 4)
```

so to bring it back to a numerical representation, you could simply call `tonumber()` on the resulting number.